# Text to Speech - highlight the read word when it is being Spoken and track speak progress

Tags: javascript, tinymce, text-to-speech, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

[image: []1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USZOJ.png

My Requirement is  i want to copy paste data to this textbox. after copying  text its formatting should not change,
one should be able to change the font size , font etc.

1. If data contains paragraph and table then it can be pasted in
   its own format.
2. Text color  and table border color in the textbox should be changed to
   white irrespective of original format color.
3. Table layout should not get disturbed in textbox.

**

***i have found solution on this and i have achieved it in web based
TinyMCE editor and JavaScript,  i am using window speech synthesis to
read the copied data in to the editor ,  when i click on read button
it reads the data but i need  to highlight the read word when it is
being Spoken***

**

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to get the job done:

1. Using the `HTMLBody` property of Outlook items which returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. The `HTMLBody` property should be an HTML syntax string.
2. Using the Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word `Document` which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.